# If I just have a single icon for my Xamarin Forms Android, do I need to create a splash screen?

Tags: xamarin.forms, icons, splash-screen

I see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen) in the Xamarin docs.

But I also see in the docs that I can do this:

```
[Activity(Label = "Test", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher", Theme = "@style/MainTheme")]
    public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
```

Do they both do the same thing or is there a difference? If I want just a single icon to show when the application is starting then can anyone explain which would be the best way to go or do I even have a choice which I can use?

Comment: the icon is used on the Android main screen & menus to launch your app.  The splash screen is a UI that is displayed while your app spins up.

Comment: If you want a simple icon to display you can go with the second one. If you need complex and solid splash use the first one